# How to get highest occuring value from table using another column as a multiplier instead of row count MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average

Suppose there is a

```
 dataset(col1,col2) 

with values (1000,1),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(999999,3)
```

.
Here is the query you can copypaste:

```
create temporary table tb4 (a INT,b INT);
INSERT INTO tb4(a,b)values(1000,1),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(199999,3);
Select avg(tb4.b) from tb4;
```

Here I want to get 3. How to do it? As you see AVG in this setting returns 2 because it is indeed the most commonly occuring value.. Row-wise, that is. But I want it to treat 'a' as as "row-count" and return 3 as if there were the amount of 'a' column rows in the table (so to speak) basically using column named 'a' as a "common"-ity increaser. But how to do it in a query I do not know. Thanks

Comment: The average of the `b` column isn't 3, it's 2.  Why would you expect 3 as the average?

Comment: the avg .. is 2  .... why you want 3??  3 is the max

Comment: Please explain your questions clearly

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I rephrased the question to better fit what I was envisioning... Sorry if it unclear before.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want a *weighted* average.  You can do:

```
select sum(x * y * 1.0) / sum(x)
```

Comment: Almost there! Is it possible to make it return 5 instead of 4 if th dataset(x,y) is (1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(20,3),(20,5),(20,5) ?

Comment: @MoeEpo . . . I assume that is just a question of rounding up or down.

Comment: could you please review my question? I think it is more clarified now